# Is Wolfram wrong about unique 3-colorability, or am I just confused?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

The illustration on [Wolfram's page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Uniquelyk-ColorableGraph.html) claims to present a uniquely colorable, triangle-free graph. However, this seems to be blatantly false: the graph has a symmetry with respect to a reflection through the horizontal axis, and we can use this symmetry to construct a new colouring not isomorphic to the original one.

Am I missing something obvious here, or is the illustration simply wrong? If it's the latter, what is a simple example of a triangle-free, uniquely 3-colourable graph?

[image]

Comment: My graph theory is weak, and as such it is not obvious to me why the reflective symmetry should guarantee a coloring not isomorphic to the original one. Can you elaborate just a bit or provide a reference?

Comment: @J.Loreaux As defined by Wolfram (and I think this is the usual definition) two colourings are distinct if they give a different partition (see the linked page, first definition).

Comment: Has anyone informed the website maintainers about the error?

Comment: @MarkS. I just did.

Comment: By the way, it's quite ironic that the entry on Wolfram under discussion specifically mentions two instances from the literature where incorrect examples of uniquely 3-colourable graphs are given, and makes a point of explaining why they are incorrect.

Comment: But doesn't the left-right mirror symmetry (even with the extra edge mentioned in [n55's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1356439/97480) just correspond to swapping red and green and, hence, preserve the partition?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: The issue is not left-right symmetry, but up-down symmetry. The right-left symmetry is indeed harmless.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, Wolfram is wrong in this case. I just checked the archives of the Journal of Combinatorial Theory (where the erratum to the paper in question is published) and the two top vertices are supposed to be connected by an edge.

I cannot provide a link because it requires a login, and I was able to log in through my university's subscription to the journal.

[image: Graph with added line]

Comment: This would seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I assume you mean the articles
[doi:10.1016/S0021-9800(70)80027-8](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(70)80027-8) and
[doi:10.1016/S0021-9800(69)80086-4](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(69)80086-4). They seem to be freely accessible. (They are marked as Open Archive.)

Comment: Wow, I didn't see that... Thanks for letting me know!